# npm boostrap version (4.1.0) doesn't add all css properties to css 'background' tag

Tags: css, angular, npm

I have an Angular 5.2.10 project that uses angular-cli and boostrap version: 4.0.0-beta.2 version with the following css class:

```
.en-icon-24 {
  background: url(../../../../assets/img/icons.png) -370px 0px;      
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

In the browser everything appears ok:

[image]

The problem: if I upgrade my npm version of boostrap from 4.0.0-beta.2 to 4.1.0 then in the browser the following happens:

[image]

And of course when this happens the images is not correctly positioned anymore (the -370px and 0 are missing)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use background-image: url(../../../../assets/img/icons.png); background-position: -370px 0;  separately.

Comment: Already know this works, thank you. The idea is not to add the background-position property separately. If you have a monster project it would be hard to modify this everywhere + you need to test.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code like this

```
.en-icon-24 {
  background: url('/assets/img/icons.png') -370px 0px;      
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```